# CSS - Simple DIV layout issue

Tags: jquery, css, layout, html

Basically I want to have four main divs for my basic layout:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="header">header</div>
      <div class="navigation">navigation</div>
      <div class="content">contents</div>
      <div class="footer">footer</div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I set the height of `html`, `body` and `.container` to 100% in CSS. Then `.header`, `.navigation` and `.footer` heights to 60px.

I would like the `.content` `div` to either match the height of the content that's within it, or if there's just a bit of content, have the `.content` `div` expand to take up the rest of the `window` `height` that isn't occupied by the `header` and `footer`. I can't get this to work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think their is a way to do this with just html and CSS  basically what you are wanting is 100% -180px as a `min-height`.  The only way I could think of to do this would be a javascript that gets the `height` as pixels and then subtracts 180px from them. 60 pixels for the `header`, `navigation`, and `footer`.

```
var winHeight = $(window).height();
winHeight = winHeight - 180;

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".content").css('min-height', winHeight);
});
```

This also needs to be qualified that if they are not running their browsers as maximized then the view area will be different.  You could check for an on `onresize event`, but that's a different question. :)

Comment: Yes this essentially what I want. I was hoping to not have to rely on javascript to achieve this. But I might just go this route anyhow since Javascript is pretty much essential for the web-app I'm working on anyhow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not as simple as it sounds. Here is a link to a css driven solution by Matthew James Taylor. It is a single column full page design, but there are links to 2 and 3 column designs as well. I use this (and credit it) in pages I build that use this concept.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-1-column-full-page-pixels.htm

Comment: This article is outdated and will not work with modern browsers such as google chrome

Comment: @Tim B James: It's odd that you say that because I develop my pages specifically for chrome using this basic layout, and it works just fine for me. I admittedly don't use the 1-column layout so that one very well could be useless, but the 2 and 3 columns behave in Chrome exactly as advertised. I'm also not suggesting using this pattern out of the box. As with anything, OP should study how it is done on those pages to understand it before employing it.

Comment: yeah the 1-column layout doesnt work in chrome as it does not fill out vertically as explained in the article. Not sure about the others though, but i think as an asnwer to this question it wouldnt work.